# can't modify input data on chart LCJS

Tags: javascript, typescript, lightningchart

I'm using [LightingChart JS](https://lightningchart.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v4.1.1/index.html) for creating some scrolling line charts.

I followed through an official tutorial by the devs on Youtube and it worked fine with automatic generated data. Now i want to modify the input to an json file that only contains a list of integers (that represents their Y value).

To plot this data, the tutorial used other package named [XYData](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@arction/xydata). The following code is the part where the automatic data is generated (and properly working).

```js
createProgressiveTraceGenerator()
    .setNumberOfPoints(100000)
    .generate()//.setData()
    .setStreamBatchSize(100)
    .setStreamInterval(1000/60)
    .setStreamRepeat(true)  
    .toStream()
    .forEach(dataPoint => {
      series.add(dataPoint)
    })
```

I saw in the [ChartXY docs](https://arction.github.io/xydata/globals.html#createprogressivetracegenerator) that returned object of the method`generate()` used by the returned object by  `createProgressiveTraceGenerator()` returns an object of the [*DataHost* class.](https://arction.github.io/xydata/classes/datahost.html) Furthermore, this *DataHost* object has the setData() method, that can be used to overwrite the automatic generated points for my json file.

Problem is: i don't know how to transform my list of dictionaries into an DataHost to input

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

LineSeries takes in data as lists of JavaScript objects, which are fundamentally equal to "dictionaries". Also JSON = Javascript object notation, so suffice to say you shouldn't need large transformations to get the data in.

For example,

```
LineSeries.add([ { x: 0, y: 0 }, { x: 1, y: 1 } ])
```

https://lightningchart.com/js-charts/api-documentation/v4.1.1/classes/LineSeries.html#add